# Laravel 5 - Laravel\Collective

Tags: html, laravel-5, tags

I am using the Laravel/Collective as a form helper in Laravel 5, however when i create my forms it only outputs the html markup and not the form controls as expected.

I have added "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0" to my composer.json, ran composer update.

Added 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' to the providers array in in the config.app and 'Form'      => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade','Html'      => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade' in the aliases array in config.app file.

My form code: 
{!! Form::model($currency, ['route'=>['currency.update', $currency->id], 'method'=>'PUT'])  !!}

```
            {{ Form::label('currency', 'Currency Code: ', ['class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label']) }}
            {{ Form::text('currency', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::label('description', 'Currency Description: ', ['class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label']) }}
            {{ Form::text('description', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}

            {{ Form::label('is_active', 'Is Active? ',  ['class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label'])}}
            {{ Form::checkbox('is_active', $currency->is_active) }}

            {{ Form::button('Submit') }}

            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Output is the html markup:

```html
 <label for="currency" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Currency Code: </label> <input class="form-control" name="currency" type="text" value="GBP" id="currency"> <label for="description" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Currency Description: </label> <input class="form-control" name="description" type="text" value="British Pound" id="description"> <label for="is_active" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Is Active? </label> <input name="is_active" type="checkbox" value="0" id="is_active"> <button type="button">Submit</button>
```

I know its probably something silly i missed but i've been stumped so far, any assistance or advice would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that laravel is escaping the output. Try wrapping your code in {!! !!} tags instead.

Like this:

```
{!! Form::label('currency', 'Currency Code: ', ['class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::text('currency', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Laravel Collective's Form and Html package correctly. The issue you're facing is that you're only getting the HTML markup and not the form controls when you're rendering the form. This usually happens when the Bootstrap CSS library is not loaded in your project.

Laravel Collective's Form package heavily relies on Bootstrap CSS classes to render the form controls. Therefore, you need to include the Bootstrap CSS library in your project. You can either download and include it manually or use a Content Delivery Network (CDN) to include it in your project.

Here's an example of how you can include Bootstrap CSS using a CDN:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

Add this code in the  section of your HTML document, and you should be able to see the form controls rendered correctly.

If you're already using Bootstrap in your project, make sure that it's included correctly and that there are no conflicts with other CSS libraries.

I hope this helps!